# Kill not killing forked process after sleep in perl

Tags: perl, fork

there. I'm trying to do the following:

- Fork.
- Launched a desktop application.
- Wait for 2 secs.
- Kill the desktop application.

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cmd = ('calc.exe');

my $pid = fork();
die "fork() failed: $!" unless defined $pid;

if ($pid) {
    system @cmd;    
}

sleep 2;
kill 'TERM' => $pid;
```

The application is launched correctly but it doesn't kill after the two seconds. I know I missing something, I hope someone can point me to the right direction. Right know I'm testing this code in windows 7 SP1 with perl 5.32.1 bundled with msys2.

Answer (score 2):

You have up to four processes here: Parent, child, shell, app. You're killing the child, not the app. Use `exec` instead of `system` and use the `exec BLOCK LIST` form to avoid a shell.

Even then, that may not work. It depends on how well msys2 emulates `fork` and `exec`. A better solution might be to use the Windows system calls (`CreateProcess` and `ExitProcess`) instead of emulations of unix system calls.

Comment: OK, I'm killing the child and not the app...so, taking my example, how can I kill the app?

Comment: I told you two ways in my answer...